# ArcGIS 10.3 geocoder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

I recently upgraded, desktop, server, engine and SDE to 10.3, and of course had to upgrade some other features and extensions. It seems that now that I've upgraded to 10.3 my new 10.3 geocoders will not find or identify addresses. Strangely, when using the Address Inspector on the Geocoding Tool bar it will identify address with the 10.3 GC, but won't find any when using the search bar.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded a client environment from 9.3.1 to 10.3. They had major issues with upgrading their geocoders - basically the changes were so vast that they had to completely rebuild the geocoder. Turns out with most releases, the geocoder fields change, so you just have to go through the docs and remap the fields yourself. In my client's case, the differences were so vast, remapping wasn't even an option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer and fix was rather mundane. I just had to remap some of the fields in the geocoder and things worked fine. It also seemed to help if I made the geocoder more generalized and removed "City and State" fields.
W